# How to mute android talkback on seekbar progress

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

My app's accessibility for video player announces every progress changes on the seekbar when the talkback is enabled. Ex: on progress, "progress 26%", "Progress 27%" ... etc

Is there a way to disable this so the seekbar is still selectable but its changes not announced?

Answer (score -1):

I believe TalkBack only announces updates to a widget's state if it has accessibility focus. So if you place focus somewhere else, it should quiet down.